# How to looping automatically each group (category)

Tags: php, mysql, loops

hy guys , i want to make looping.. automatically .. but i dont know may i wrong put while or wrong make a looping?

my database

tabel : kt_barang

```
    kd_kategori | nama_kategori
    1           | A
    2           | B
    3           | C
```

tabel : t_barang

```
kd_barang  | kategori 
11         | 1
12         | 1
13         | 2
14         | 3
15         | 3
16         | 3
```

Query table

```
CREATE TABLE kt_barang
    (`kd_kategori` int, `nama_kategori` varchar(9))
;  
INSERT INTO kt_barang
    (`kd_kategori`, `nama_kategori`)
VALUES
    (1, ' A '),
    (2, ' B '),
    (3, ' C ');

    CREATE TABLE t_barang
    (`kd_barang` int, `kategori` int)
;  
INSERT INTO t_barang
    (`kd_barang`, `pnaik`)
VALUES
    ('11', 1),
    ('12', 1),
    ('13', 2),
    ('14', 3),
    ('15', 3),
    ('16', 3)
;
```

my code

```
$arr=array();
$qw=mysql_query("select * from kt_barang",$con);
    while($h=mysql_fetch_array($qw)){
          $arr[]=$h['kd_kategori'];
    }
$n = 0;
$c = count($arr);

while ($n < $c) {
   $a = $arr[$n];

   echo "kategori :".$a ."<br>";

   $q=mysql_query("select * from t_barang where kategori='$a'",$con);


while($h=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    $daftar.='
    <tr>
    <td>'.$h['kd_barang'].'</td>';
    $daftar.='
    </tr>
    ';
}

   $n++;
}


?>

        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" border="1">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center;" width="100">KODE</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <?php echo $daftar;?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

output now still like this 
the table still one ..

```
kategori 1
kategori 2
kategori 3
---------------
    Kode       | 
    11         | 
    12         | 
    13         | 
    14         | 
    15         | 
    16         | 
---------------
```

BUT i want this output guys .. 
i want the table display three , because kt_barang has 3 ,

```
kategori 1
---------------
    Kode       | 
    11         | 
    12         | 
---------------

kategori 2
---------------
    Kode       | 
    13         | 
---------------

kategori 3
---------------
    Kode       | 
    14         | 
    15         | 
    16         | 
---------------
```

may i wrong put while or wrong make a looping? i dont know .. may you know how to fix it ? Thanks so much

Comment: You told us something that is not true. Because you have in your code `<tr><td>...</td><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>` which means you must have 3 column table, but the output posted has only 1 column tables... So could you explain that?

Comment: i was edit, sorry .. my all code still there ..

Answer (score 0):

it can be done with one query

```
$q=mysql_query("select a.kd_kategori,a.nama_kategori, b.kd_barang from kt_barang as a, t_barang as b where a.kd_kategori = b.kategori";);
```

Comment: yes @grumpy ,  it can be done by query .. but i want to using loop like that because i wanna using it for next proccess .. 
by the way , your query cant work

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your particular issue and logic. But just mu guess what is 100% wrong. You are mixing `echo` with `$daftar.='`. You should choose one. I believe `$daftar.='` is better trick. so.

```
while ($n < $c) {
   $a = $arr[$n];

    $daftar.= "kategori :".$a ."<br>";

   $q=mysql_query("select * from t_barang where kategori='$a'",$con);


while($h=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    $no++;
    $daftar.='
    <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center;">'.$h['kategori'].'</td>
    <td>'.$h['kd_barang'].'</td>
    <td>'.$h['nama_barang'].'</td>';

    $daftar.='
    </tr>
    ';

}

   $n++;
}

    $daftar.="<br><br><br>";
```